# How can I resolve the Android Studio Build Output error

Tags: android, android-studio, build, output

Trying to build the app but have got the error:  [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Ycc.jpg) [Confugure image asset1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D6E5.jpg)
[Confugure image asset2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzQEj.jpg)
[Confugure image asset3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsN5n.jpg)
`ERROR:C:\Users\Alex\AndroidStudioProjects\Lm2\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.lm2:mipmap/ic_launcher_background) not found.`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `How can I resolve this?` by creating the resource that aren't found

Comment: Where do you keep your ic_launcher_foreground an backgroud  images in the project?

Comment: Added screenshots 'Confugure image assets'. Please explain what exactly I need to do. The first app :/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have

- put your launcher icons into the **mipmap** folder where they should always go.
- added your adaptive icon to the app’s manifest.xml for “android:icon” (android:roundIcon) attribute .

**Fist hand try**: Clean your project and Rebuild

**Probable Issue reason**: Malformed XML:

**Solution:**

- Check if you have anything duplicated by mistake in your XML
- Try **Analyze > Inspect Code** it will redirect you to the exact error.

Comment: >> put your launcher icons into the mipmap folder where they should always go.
They should be in Every mipmap folders (mipmap-anydpi-v26, mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi ...) ?

Comment: >>added your adaptive icon to the app’s manifest.xml for “android:icon” (android:roundIcon) attribute . – 
Do you mean the path to my icon? Instead of "        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"" it should be "        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round/myicon.png?""

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to put the launcher icon into the mipmap folder for all the device resolutions (default icons will already be there, just replace them with your icon),
2.  No, full path needed. Only put this==> 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"